# S3 Butcket Site With Gatsby React Router

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gatsby

i want to host a gatsbyjs site on s3. i have put one up but only the index.html page is working.

some something like `mydomain.com` works but `mydomain.com/docs` fails because it seems to be trying to look inside a folder. the routes are handled by gatsbys and im open to trying to set up a hash router, [doesnt seem a promising direction](https://www.reddit.com/r/gatsbyjs/comments/dhs66z/is_it_possible_to_use_hash_routing_in_a_gatsby/)

im using aws cdk for my deployment with the following code:

```
const frontBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, `${context.appName}-${context.environment}`, {
      bucketName: `${context.appName}-${context.environment}`,
      websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
      publicReadAccess: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    new BucketDeployment(this, `deployment-${context.environment}`, {
      sources: [Source.asset("../Frontend")],
      destinationBucket: frontBucket,
    });

    // Create the CloudFront Distribution
    const cfDist = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, `${context.appName}-dist-${context.environment}`, {
      originConfigs: [
        {
          s3OriginSource: {
            s3BucketSource: frontBucket,
          },
          behaviors: [
            {
              isDefaultBehavior: true,
              defaultTtl: cdk.Duration.seconds(1)
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
      viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      viewerCertificate: cloudfront.ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate(cert, {
        aliases: [recordName],
        sslMethod: cloudfront.SSLMethod.SNI,
        securityPolicy: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2021
      }),
      errorConfigurations: [
        {
          errorCode: 404,
          responseCode: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/index.html',
        },
      ],
    });
```

i recently added the configuration for `errorConfigurations` to redirect to the index, if it cant find something, but it doesnt seem to work. does anyone know what i might be doing wrong here?